# Change colors of spans when hovering parent div

Tags: html, css, hover

I have a site-title which is split up in two spans, each containing one word. What I want to accomplish is, when you hover the entire site-title the two words switch respective color. Here is the HTML:

```css
.site-title a span.custom-title2 {
  color: #C4CB92;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
}
.site-title a:hover span.custom-title2 {
  color: #EAE1DA;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
}
.site-title a span.custom-title {
  color: #EAE1DA;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
}
.site-title a:hover span.custom-title:hover {
  color: #C4CB92;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

```html
 <h1 class="site-title">
        <a title="FOOBAR" href="#">
            <span class="custom-title">FOO</span>
            <span class="custom-title2">BAR</span>
        </a>
    </h1>
```

I made a codepen to illustrate the desired effect.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jPXymZ

My problem in the meantime is that the desired effect only works when I hover FOO. That is both FOO and BAR change color. But if I hover BAR, only BAR change color.

Comment: .site-title a:hover span.custom-title2 should be .site-title a:hover span.custom-title2:hover

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should target `.site-title:hover` instead of `a:hover` in order to get the effect in both cases.

```css
.site-title a span.custom-title2 {
  color: #C4CB92;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
}
.site-title:hover a span.custom-title2 {
  color: #EAE1DA;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
}
.site-title a span.custom-title {
  color: #EAE1DA;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
}
.site-title:hover a span.custom-title {
  color: #C4CB92;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="site-title">
        <a title="FOOBAR" href="#">
            <span class="custom-title">FOO</span>
            <span class="custom-title2">BAR</span>
        </a>
    </h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

This:
`.site-title a:hover span.custom-title:hover` should be this:
`.site-title a:hover span.custom-title`. The second `:hover` is unnecessary.
Also you don't need to add the transition on the `:hover` state as well. It's enough if it's on your custom-title class.